# How to cluster data based on direct and indirect connections in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, cluster-analysis

I've got a list of data that I need to cluster in Python efficiently (total of 8mio KV-Pairs).

Example:

```
K1 = {V1, V2, V3}
K2 = {V1, V4}
K3 = {V5}
K4 = {V6}
K5 = {V1, V6}
```

Outcome:

```
C1 = {K1, K2, K4, K5}
C2 = {K3}
```

- C1 contains K1, K2, K5 because they all contain V1 (direct connection)
- C1 contains K4 since V6 is present in K5 and it leads in a connection to the others (indirect connection)
- C2 contains K3 because it does not have a connection to any KV-Pair present in C1

One way to solve it would be to firstly create temporary clusters TC that only consider the direct connections:

```
TC1 = {K1, K2, K5}
TC2 = {K3}
TC2 = {K4, K5}
```

And then merge all duplicate occurrences of K into the final cluster C:

```
C1 = {K1, K2, K4, K5}
C2 = {K3}
```

However, this approach would lead in a large complexity and I thought there may be a more efficient solution.

Is there any mathematical problem that describes this? or a related problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`networkx.connected_compontents()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#connected-components):

```py
import networkx as nx

graph = {
    "K1": {"V1", "V2", "V3"},
    "K2": {"V1", "V4"},
    "K3": {"V5"},
    "K4": {"V6"},
    "K5": {"V1", "V6"},
}

inv_graph = {}
G = nx.Graph()

for k, v in graph.items():
    nx.add_path(G, v)
    for i in v:
        inv_graph.setdefault(i, set()).add(k)

out = []
for c in nx.connected_components(G):
    tmp = set()
    for i in c:
        tmp |= inv_graph[i]
    out.append(tmp)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
 [
   {'K2', 'K1', 'K5', 'K4'}, 
   {'K3'}
 ]
```